# getting a list of all wordpress urls affected by updating a post's taxonomy and terms

Tags: wordpress

When we create or update a post, we may modify not only its title and post content but also its associated taxonomy and terms. And this change affects not only the corresponding post url but also the associated taxonomy and term urls listing that post. For example, if we add some category.tagX to our post, then the /category/tagX url will be affected too.

is there an easy way to get all of the possible WordPress urls that may be affected by that post update?